# Best way for include external javascript call into website

Tags: javascript, analytics

I have a web platform that performs data processing in relation to visits recived by my client's websites.
For capture data I need, in each page to monitor, to insert the call to my javascript that makes the collection of data in a db. 
For now, the only thing that came to my mind was to provide the javascript code to be inserted to the customer in the  section of specific page like this:

```
<script src="https://www.example.com/datascan/tk/SL-TK51124897-ME.js"></script>
```

Google, with analytics, for example, performs a similar operation but in a different way, by providing the javascript code to be inserted at the end of the `<body>`.

Someone have direct experience in this area? Which solution in terms of safety, performance and comfort you suggest? Is possible to enter the code on one page so that it can handle all the pages in that domain without repeating it in each of them?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your code will block execution till it's loaded. Unless you specifically want to do that, it's generally better to give them a snippet of code that will asynchronously load the script file you want.

Comment: *"so that it can handle all the pages in that domain without repeating it in each of them?"* That's outside the scope of the script. It's already up to the user of the code if he/she wants it on all pages.

Comment: Do you have any examples of snippet of code that will asynchronously load the script? thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the pages are statically generated (each page is hardcoded in different files) you have to include the line in each file between the  tags

If the head module is dynamically created (works as a module which is included in each page) you can just put it in the said module.
e.g. Wordpress https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/header.php

If you provide more info about the structure of the site it will be easier to help.

Comment: Thanks. The structure of site cab be of any type because for any website we can provide service